# How can I group on a specific amount of rows using LinQ?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq

I am creating a score-tracking web application for my friends and I to use. The tracker have to group the scores based on how many rounds the player with the least amount of rounds have been playing.

Example: If I have played 6 rounds, and a friend of mine has only played 4, then all of his rounds would be counting in the tournament and only the 4 best of mine would be taken to account.

This is what I have so far:

```
[ActionName("List")]
public async Task<IActionResult> List()
{
    var allData = await _cosmosDbService.GetScoresAsync(
        "SELECT * FROM c");
    var countRecordData = allData.GroupBy(l => l.Player).Select(cl => new Score
    {
        Player = cl.Count().ToString()
    }).ToList();

    var minRecord = countRecordData.Min(record => record.Player);
    int minRecordInt = Int32.Parse(minRecord);

    var sumData = allData.GroupBy(l => l.Player).Select(cl => new Score
    {
        Player = cl.First().Player,
        Points = cl.Sum(c => c.Points),
        Strokes = cl.Sum(c => c.Points),
    }).ToList();
        
    return View(sumData);
}
```

the minRecord is only used to get the player with least amount of records(number of least amount). I am not using it anywhere else.

Here is the Score model:

```
public class Score
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Player")]
    public string Player { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Course")]
    public string Course { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Points")]
    public int Points { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Strokes")]
    public int Strokes { get; set; }
}
```

Does anyone know how I can reach this requirement?

Comment: Also having your `Player` class, example input and output would help.

Comment: what exactly are you stuck on here? This reads a lot like can someone just do this for me, kinda question, which isn't going to get much love

Comment: @A.Grefslie: I think your question is fine (perhaps not super clear but I think I understand  the problem). You quickly reacted to the issue with the source code and I don't see this as a bad question.

Comment: Can't figure out how I can group the scores based on how many rounds the player with the least amount of rounds have been playing. That means that if I have 6 rounds played and my friend have 4 rounds played, all of his rounds will count and only my 4 best will count. So two of my worst rounds are excluded.

Comment: To limit points calculation to `minRecordInt` matches, try changing points calculation to `Points = cl.OrderByDescending(c=>c.Points).Take(minRecordInt).Sum(c => c.Points)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close to achieve what you want. Here is my take on what I believe you are trying to do.

If the amount of data is small it doesn't matter that you are using `GroupBy` multiple times but it might be better to create the groups only once:

```
var groupings = allData
    .GroupBy(
        score => score.Player,
        (player, scores) => new
        {
            Player = player,
            Scores = scores.ToList() 
        })
    .ToList();
```

Calling `ToList` will ensure that the collection of scores for each player are enumerated and allocated into lists.

I'm not sure about the part where you determine the minimum number of records. It looks odd to compute the minimum of the `Player` property which I assume is the name of the player.

Here I compute the minimum number of scores for all players:

```
var minScoreCount = groupings.Min(grouping => grouping.Scores.Count);
```

In the last part you have to use `Take(minScoreCount)` to only take the first N scores for each player. I think this is the part that you are missing in your own code.

```
var sumData = groupings.Select(grouping => new Score
{
    Player = grouping.Player,
    Points = grouping.Scores
        .OrderByDescending(score => score.Points)
        .Take(minScoreCount)
        .Sum(score => score.Points),
    Strokes = grouping.Scores
        .OrderBy(score => score.Strokes)
        .Take(minScoreCount)
        .Sum(score => score.Strokes)
}).ToList();
```

If you didn't have the requirement to sort the scores differently for `Points` and `Strokes` you could sort the scores before the `ToList` inside the `GroupBy` reducing the number of times the code is traversing the lists of scores.

Comment: It groups correctly, but I can't get the sorting right. For some reason it gets more or less a random order in both points and strokes

Comment: @A.Grefslie: Sorting is used to produce "top" scores as you have defined in a comment. That part is certainly not random and with the same input it will always produce the same output. However, as it seems to not produce the desired output you need to more clearly explain your requirements and perhaps provide an example that demonstrates the problem. By doing this you might even discover how my answer can be modified to match your true requirements.

Comment: im sorry I was thinking about this wrong. You are correct, and your solution meet the requirement perfectly! Thank u again for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how pretty it is, but here you go. You can do it like this:

```
[ActionName("List")]
public async Task<IActionResult> List()
{
    var allData = await _cosmosDbService.GetScoresAsync(
        "SELECT * FROM c");
    var playerRounds = allData.GroupBy(l => l.Player);
    var minRounds = playerRounds.Min(x => x.Count());

    var sumData = playerRounds.Select(cl => new Score
    {
        Player = cl.First().Player,
        Points = cl.OrderByDescending(x => x.Points).Take(minRounds).Sum(c => c.Points),
        Strokes = cl.OrderByDescending(x => x.Points).Take(minRounds).Sum(c => c.Points),
    }).ToList();

    return View(sumData);
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/ho1psw